# SQLAlchemy UPDATE record flask

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, sql-update

The code below adds a new record to table CC5. I need to instead add a record - update it. How to do that?

view.py

```
    @app.route('/dodajc5', methods=['POST'])
def dodajc5():
        if request.form['przycisk'] == 'Zapisz':
                record = CC5(si=request.form['si'], snd=request.form['snd'], snh=request.form['snh'], sno=request.form['sno'],
                             so=request.form['so'], ss=request.form['ss'], xa=request.form['xa'], xh=request.form['xh'],
                             xi=request.form['xi'], xnd=request.form['xnd'], xp=request.form['xp'], xs=request.form['xs'])
                dbu.session.add(record)
                dbu.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('c5'))
```

models.py

```
class CC1(dbu.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cc1'
    id = dbu.Column('id',dbu.Integer, primary_key = True)
    si = dbu.Column('si', dbu.Float)
    [...]
    xp = dbu.Column('xp', dbu.Float)
    xs = dbu.Column('xs', dbu.Float)

    def __init__(self,si,snd,snh,sno,so,ss,xa,xh,xi,xnd,xp,xs):
            self.si = si
            self.snd = snd
         [...]
            self.xp = xp
            self.xs = xs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do it the same way you would in real-life.  Get the existing record, make the changes and save them. Assuming `form['si']` is a primary key:

```
if request.form['...'] = '...':
    pk = request.form['si']
    record = dbu.session.query(CC5).get(pk)
    record.so = request.form['so']
    record.snd = request.form['snd']
    # etc...
    db.session.commit
```

Read More: [SQLAlchemy "Adding and Updating Objects" Documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#adding-and-updating-objects)